# what is the maximum integer(unsigned integer) value that glsl can support?

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, opengl-es-3.1

What's the maximum value of integer and unsigned integer that can be used in shader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For OpenGL ES 3.x "lowp int" must be at least 9-bit twos complement, "mediump int" must be at least 16-bit twos complement, and "highp int" must be at least 32-bit twos complement.

| Precision | Signed range | Unsigned range |
| --- | --- | --- |
| lowp | -2<sup>8</sup> to 2<sup>8</sup>-1 | 0 to 2<sup>9</sup>-1 |
| mediump | -2<sup>15</sup> to 2<sup>15</sup>-1 | 0 to 2<sup>16</sup>-1 |
| highp | -2<sup>31</sup> to 2<sup>31</sup>-1 | 0 to 2<sup>32</sup>-1 |

**Reference:** Section 4.5.1 Range and Precision (page 53 in the PDF).

https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_3.00.pdf